# Including Vue js instances on all pages, even when element doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my web app I make use of Vue.js for a number of small components around the site. I store the Vue instances in their own js files which I concatonate, minify etc using gulp.

There is a small issue where if the target element for a particular Vue instance doesn't exist on the page a warning appears in the console:

> `[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #vueElement`

Although this doesn't harm anything as it is it left me wondering what the correct approach is to loading my Vue instances. Is there a way to prevent it firing if the target element isn't there?

Comment: this answer explains more http://stackoverflow.com/a/37902612/580651

Answer (score 4):

```
var element = document.getElementById('vueElement');

if(element != null)
{
    // your code will be here, an example is shown below
    var app = new Vue(
       el: '#vueElement'
    );
}
```

I Hope this works!

Comment: you can just do `if (element)`

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any build-in way of doing this.

If you provide the `el` option in the constructor the Vue instance will automatically compile.

If you don't provide the `el`option, you can manually compile the component using the $mount method.

So you can write something like this:

```
var app = new Vue({}); //don't include the el option here

if(document.getElementById("vueElement")) {
    app.$mount("#vueElement");      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, for this purpose I use a function that will initialize Vue only if the target element exists:

```
function vueInit(elementId, options) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    if (element) {
        options.el = element;
        new Vue(options);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
vueInit("app", {
    data: {
        message: "It works!"
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/14194/

Comment: This way, you'll have to have jQuery or other query selector framework or library to deal with `$(selector)`, personally I'd suggest you to use the native / vanilla way (`document.getElementById`) as you won't need a whole library just to this purpose. =) Check @Needpoule's answer.

Comment: jQuery was not really the point of my answer... I removed it anyways. My point is to create a reusable function. You can use the selector you want inside it, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I still prefer @Needpoule's answer, though.